# Displaying result from MongoDB collection with Pug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, pug

I have a **MongoDB** collection and it's structure like this;

```
{
    "_id": "4rc4f9653fc4ff04dd7d31h6",
    "title": "my title",
    "url": "https://myurl.com",
    "author": "john",
    "created": {
        "$date": "2020-05-20T04:12:47.457Z"
    },
    "vote": 1619
}
```

And i have below `pug` layout;

```
block content
  h1 #{title}
  ul.list-group
    each entry, i in entries
      li.list-group-item
        a(href=entry.url, target='new')= entry.title
        |, 
        span.text-success=entry.author
        |, 
        span.text-success=entry.vote
```

This is working fine and the outcome is like this;

[mytitle](https://myurl.com), john, 1619

I would like to add date field as well. So my final outcome should be like this;

[mytitle](https://myurl.com), john, 1619, 2020-05-20

I tried to add `created` field as shown below but this is not bringing any value for created. Any idea what am i missing here?

```
a(href=entry.url, target='new')= entry.title
|, 
span.text-success=entry.author
|, 
span.text-success=entry.vote
|, 
span.text-success=entry.created
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data, `created` is an object, not a date string. To access the date string, you'd need to do:

```
span.text-success= entry.created['$date']
```

Comment: This gives me error: "Cannot read property '$date' of undefined"

Comment: You're calling it from within the `each` loop?

Comment: this is my app.js by the way: Entry.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$url", author: { $first: "$author" }, vote: { $max: "$vote" }, url: { $first: "$url" }, title: { $first: "$title" } } },{ $sort:{ vote:-1} },{ $limit: 500 }]).exec(function(err, entries).. I wonder should i need to include date here..

Comment: Yes, otherwise it's not being passed to Pug.